# How to convert a integer to a binary in C++20?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary, c++20

I am trying to convert a char into a binary. So first I used `static_cast< int >(letter)` then I used `cout<<format("The binary value is {:b}",integer_value);`.

I am using C++20 in Visual Studio 2019, so that is why I used format. However, I used it but it gives the wrong value. For example, I typed in `k` and it showed a binary value of  `0b1101011`, but this is wrong and on the internet I checked it and `k` should equal `01101011`. My full code is shown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Enter a letter: " << endl;
char lett{};
cin >> lett;

switch (lett)
{
case 'A':
case 'a':
case 'i':
case 'I':
case 'o':
case 'O':
case 'u':
case 'U':
cout << "You entered a vowel \n";
break;

default:
cout << "The letter is not a vowel \n";
break;

}



if (islower(lett))
{
    cout << "You entered a lower case letter \n";
}
else if (isupper(lett))
{
    cout << "The letter is not lower case \n";
}



// conver letter to lowercase and binary value 
int inti{(static_cast<int>(lett))};

cout << format("The lower case letter is {} and its binary value is 0b{:b} \n\n\n", static_cast<char>(tolower(lett)), inti);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `01101011` and `1101011` are the same number. If you want leading zeros, you can use pass a width to the formatter like `0b{:08b}`.

Comment: There are several things that could go wrong, like e.g. input, conversion to a different integer type, or finally the formatting and output. Reduce the scope to find out which of them failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output shown is *numerically* correct – it's just missing a leading zero. You can force the addition of leading zeros by specifying a field width (8) and add the `0` in the specifier.

The following line (using `{:08b}`) will output your binary value in the desired format:

```cpp
cout << format("The lower case letter is {} and its binary value is 0b{:08b} \n\n\n", static_cast<char>(tolower(lett)), inti);
```

More details about format specifiers can be found on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification) (specifically, the "**fill and align**" and "**sign, #, and 0**" sections, for this case).